# ANTLR4 not recognising a rule

Tags: java-8, antlr4

in my g4 file, I have defined an integer like so:

```
INT: '0'
   | '-'? [1-9] [0-9_]*
   ;
   // no leading zeros are allowed!
```

A parser rule uses this like so:

```
versionDecl: PACK_VERSION_DECL INT;
```

However, when ANTLR comes across one, it doesn't recognise it, and throws a NullPointerException if I run  `ctx.INT().getText()`:

```
@Override
public void exitVersionDecl(VersionDeclContext ctx) {
    System.out.println(ctx.INT().getText());
}
```

Log:

```
line 1:13 mismatched input '6' expecting INT
[...]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.blockypenguin.mcfs.MCFSCustomListener.exitVersionDecl(MCFSCustomListener.java:16)
    at main.antlr.MCFSParser$VersionDeclContext.exitRule(MCFSParser.java:604)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker.exitRule(ParseTreeWalker.java:47)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker.walk(ParseTreeWalker.java:30)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker.walk(ParseTreeWalker.java:28)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker.walk(ParseTreeWalker.java:28)
    at com.blockypenguin.mcfs.Main.main(Main.java:40)
```

(Unrelated output omitted for brevity)

And finally, the input I am parsing:

```
pack_version 6
```

Why does ANTLR not recognise the integer? Any help appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: That is impossible to say without seeing your entire grammar (or enough of it to be able to reproduce it). Yoiu most likely have a rule defined *before* the `INT` rule that also matches the character `'6'`.

Comment: @BartKiers oh thank you, I don't know how I didn't see that! Before the `INT` rule I'd defined a `NUMBER` rule that could match decimal-point numbers OR a regular integer. Thanks :)

Comment: Good to hear that you resolved it. I've explained it in a bit more detail as an answer: be sure to carefully read it: it's one of the things that go wrong with a lot of people starting with ANTLR.

Comment: I will, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...
>
> ```
> INT: '0'
>    | '-'? [1-9] [0-9_]*
>    ;
>    // no leading zeros are allowed!
> ```
>
> ...
>
> `line 1:13 mismatched input '6' expecting INT`

This error indicates that for the input `6`, the lexer rule `INT` was not matched. This can happen if you have a lexer rules defined *before* the `INT` rule that also matches `6`. Like this for example:

```
DIGIT
 : [0-9]
 ;

...

INT
 : '0'
 | '-'? [1-9] [0-9_]*
 ;
```

Now the input `"6"` (or any single digit) will be matched as a `DIGIT` token. Even if you have this in the parser part of your grammar:

```
parse
 : INT
 ;
```

the input `"6"` will still be tokenised as a `DIGIT` token: the lexer is not "driven" by the parser, it operates on it's own 2 rules:

1. try to match as much characters as possible for a single lexer rule
2. in case 2 or more lexer rules match the same amount of characters, let the rule defined first "win"

So, the input `"12"` will be tokenised as an `INT` token (rule 1 applies here), and input `"0"` is tokenised as a `DIGIT` token (rule 2).